# trying to get values less than using pdo

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get values less than my last value for pagination but I keep getting empty arrays even though there should be values there. Is it my syntax that is causing this or am i calling this wrong? Thank you in advance.

```
 <?php
    include("connect.php"); //connect to database
        //create query

        $get_messages_query = $db->prepare("
            SELECT * FROM `blogposts`
            WHERE `postid` < ?
            ORDER BY `postid` DESC 
            LIMIT 5
            ");
        //Homepage should have last 5 blog posts this will take the 
        //last 5 entered into the database and put them into an 
        //array
    $one = 1;
$zero = 0;

$lastpage = $_GET['id'];

$pageback = $lastpage - 1;
$pageforward = $lastpage + 1;


        $get_messages_query->execute(array($_POST['idid']));
while($row = $get_messages_query->fetch())
    {
        if($row['comments'] == $one){
            $id = $row['postid'];
        $blog_post_history .=
        '<div class="post" id="post">
        <h1>' . $row['title'] .' </h1>
        <h2>Written by: ' . $row['author'] . '</h2>
        <p>'. $row['content'] . '</p>
        <a href="addcomment.php?id='. $row['postid'] .'">Add Comment</a>
        <a href="showcomments.php?id='. $row['postid'] . '">Show Comments</a>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>';
}
    else{
        $id - $row['postid'];
        $blog_post_history .=
      '<div class="post" id="post">
       <h1>'. $row['title'] .' </h1>
        <h2>Written by: ' . $row['author'] . '</h2>
       <p>'. $row['content'] . '</p>
       <a href="viewblog.php?id='. $row['postid'] .'">View Blog</a>

       <br>
       <br>
  </div>';
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to access your result set?

Comment: I don't see where pagination comes into play here. Typically this would be executed by doing something like `LIMIT 0, 5` (for first page), `LIMIT 5, 5` (for second page), etc.  So you have a bit of a convoluted approach here.  I also don;t see where you are trying to put this data into an array, so I am not fully sure what the problem you mention is.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `$_POST['idid']` contains the integer value you think it does.  For example, if you mismatch the name of the POST parameter, or if the value is a string instead of a number, you could be searching for `postid < 0`

Enable the MySQL [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html) and you can view the final SQL -- including dynamic parameters -- as it is executed.  That's an easy way to verify that the SQL is running what you expect it to.

Of course, do this only on a development or staging instance of your database, because enabling the general query log on your production site has a high performance impact.

Also test the query in the mysql client, to see if the results are what you think they should be.  You said there "should" be data, but it's worth double-checking with a direct query, i.e. do a test without PHP/PDO involved.

Comment: Idid contains the value 9 and there are 6 more entries in blogposts that are less than that